# Is this a script mistake in Ant-Man and the Wasp movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In a scene, we see Scott's ex-wife (Maggie), her husband (Jim), and Scott's daughter (Cassey) are watching the TV and a report about a giant creature (Goliath/Scott's huge form) in the city is showing; the reporter says It is NOT KNOWN what or who that thing is.

Also, Maggie and Jim look at each other surprisingly like they don't know the identity of Goliath; but Cassey is smiling; thus she knows it is her father.

Well, people knew about the Germany incident; so the reporter makes no sense.

Also, Maggie and Jim don't know it also makes no sense; because sure they know the reason for Scott's house arrest; and well, when people do know, how can Maggie and Jim don't know the events that occurred in *Captain America: Civil War* and Ant-Man? See 1:33:18 of the film to watch that scene.

Comment: @Paulie_D Hi friend. sorry for latency. I was trying to find that scene in order to give you the correct time. see the 1:33:18 of the film to watch that scene. Paulie_D Paulie_D@

Comment: Found it and I suspect you are right. it's not really *entirely* logical that Maggie and Jim are unaware but they might not know the *full*  details of Scott's offence and secret identity. Pretty sure that the government would keep his identity secret as part of his plea deal.

Comment: What about the TV report?

Comment: What about it? I disagree that knowledge of the incident in Germany is *public* and that Ant-Man is also Giant-Man.

Comment: @Paulie_D Scott is seen when trying to rescue Cassie in his Ant-Man suit - Jim specifically works with him during this scene. While Jim may not know about Ant-Man/Giant-Man nuances, a giant person in the exact suit that Scott was using in a previous movie scene ..... is pretty connectable.

Comment: To be fair tho, I didn't read the scene as them being surprised by the identity of a Giant-Man, but that they were surprised that Scott is doing his thing, and Giant-Man is a new aspect. I read the events following Ant-Man as Jim is pretty clear that Scott is a good guy, and while the FBI are only following the law, he personally finds harassing Scott to be bs, and probably the Accords as well.

Comment: @DariM I read the scene that way because of the contrast made between Cassie's smile and Maggie's and Jim's body language

Comment: I'm with DariM.  By coincidence, I rewatched this only last night and I put their reactions down as 1) basic human shock value at the sight of a titan wading off Fisherman's Wharf  2) possibly building fear, because in the MCU, when superheroes are blatantly visible, aliens or cities start dropping out of the sky  3) wincing concern that, if it's Scott, then he's in a pile of trouble for breaking house arrest.  (Cassie, as Scott's junior partner, has bottomless faith and excited confidence in her father.)

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer: nobody knows about Germany. In *Ant Man and the Wasp*, it is mentioned that Scott helped Captain America. Now, Scott was a thief, so it is possible that people believed that Scott would have smuggled something in order to help Captain America and the other Team Cap members. Nobody would even expect him to be Ant Man.

Going back to *Civil War*, the airport battle included Black Panther, who is the king of a nation. It also included most of the Avengers, who saved the world numerous times. People were already accusing the Avengers of collateral damage and the UN would definitely try and silence the destructive stuff the Avenges did back there. They literally destroyed entire planes and half the airport. It was the safest option for them, without having to face the media or the diplomacy.

So, in that case, nobody would have recorded the events in the airport (except for Spidey), and could not figure out who Ant Man actually is. That is why no one recognized him.

Answer to a comment: Yes, Paxton knew that Scott was Ant-Man from the first movie; but Maggie (Scott's ex-wife) did not. So, even if they saw Giant-Man, Maggie would be surprised and Dave would be too, because he does not know that Scott can enlarge. Even if he did, well, nobody wants to deliberately disclose an outlaw superhero's identity, which would be the case if Dave just acted as if everything was normal.

Comment: "*the events in Leipzig*" The Leipzig-Halle Airport is actually located in Schkeuditz, not Leipzig. https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Schkeuditz https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Leipzig-Halle_Airport https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leipzig/Halle_Airport

Comment: It is definitely not Berlin

Comment: I think we can all agree that there was an airport battle?

Comment: @PNS convinced that nobody knows about Germany. But it still doesn't make sense that Scott's ex-wife and her husband didn't recognize him. Sure they knew Scott is Ant-Man in the final sequences of *Ant-Man* movie.

Comment: Scott's ex-wife didn't. Only Dave knew it, so it makes sense that he would want to hide Scott's identity.

Comment: @PNS Why should Scott's identity be hidden from his ex-wife? She is a very close friend of him. But I think she knows too. She saw that giant ant in the last sequences of *Ant-Man*. Also, she saw her child's toy train became a giant one in the same movie.